# Multi producer single consumer queue without dedicated consumer thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm writing an async application which submits elements to a work queue for processing. The requirements are:

- There is no background thread listening on the queue. Any thread that submits an element to the queue may be responsible for consuming the queue.
- There can be multiple concurrent producers, but only one thread can be the active consumer.
- If thread A submits an element but thread B is actively consuming the queue, thread A should return immediately. No waiting allowed.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
final Queue<T> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
final AtomicBoolean processing = new AtomicBoolean();

void offer(T t) {
    queue.offer(t);

    for (;;) {
        if (processing.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
            try {
                for (;;) {
                    T t = queue.poll();
                    if (t == null) {
                        break;
                    }
                    // process t
                }
            } finally {
                processing.set(false);
            }

            // see if another thread submitted an element but didn't process it
            // if not, we can break
            if (queue.isEmpty()) {
                break;
            }
        } else {
            // losers should exit
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I *think* my code works, but this problem sounds fairly standard so I would like to know if there is any textbook solution or at least a common name. So far I only find algorithms that require a worker thread to be listening on the queue.

Comment: Your first requirement doesn't make sense.  I think what you are saying is that each submitter is _possibly_ responsible for consuming the queue.

Comment: Also, you need to handle the failure case.  if the processing of "t" throws an exception, depending on how you handle that you could end with orphaned items on the queue.

Comment: @jtahlborn Thanks, "may be responsible" is a better description. For failure case let's just assume the throwable will be logged and ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct, but problem is not seen as standard: usually, having background thread is not so expensive, as:

1. Having *no finite time garantee* for producers. It is possible for some producer to work for a long time in consumer mode.
2. *Complicate* producer's code.

In any case, your question's title (`MPSC without dedicated consumer thread`) describes the problem well. For resolve it you can combine `trylock/unlock` approach with any MPSC implementation without notification mechanism. The only additional requirement to MPSC is *concurrent* `queue.isEmpty()` method, but usually it is not a problem.

Comment: Thanks! In my scenario the unfairness is intentional so yeah, that's what I'm looking for.